# Why do I need a verb to use "refrain from"?

Tags: grammar

> **Definition by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/refrain)**
>   
> to abstain from an impulse to say or do something (often followed by from):

**Synonyms:** *abstain, avoid*

**Instance *without* a verb:** I *refrain from* alcohol.

**Instance *with* a verb:** The future generation will reap the best results of civilisation by *refraining from **repeating*** mistakes of the past.

^it would be grammatically wrong if *repeat* is omitted, even though in both context it still make sense and mean same thing

**PS:** I know what is wrong and right, but I am looking for the constructive explanation behind this.

Comment: Personally, I would use *refrain* with a verb and *abstain* with a noun, so I don't see them as exact synonyms.  I'm a native speaker but I don't have a good explanation for that.

Comment: You can certainly omit the _gerund-participle_ "repeating" here. The context makes the meaning clear without it. However, as a matter of _style_, it may be more effective to include it as a way of emphasizing that the mistakes are a continuing problem. (In English, it is idiomatic to _"abstain"_, and not to _"refrain"_ from alcohol. We _refrain from_ an action like drinking, not from the substance that is drunk. The swearing off of strong drink, or any of the standard vices, is commonly called _"abstinence"_)

Comment: **refrain from mistakes** is a misuse of "refrain" on a semantic level.  We refrain from doing things that we might like to do, or refrain from doing things which we might feel we have the freedom or the right to do, because we think better of it.  *He refrained from taking another piece of cake.  She refrained from revealing the secret. The parent refrained from punishing the child.*  **abstain from an impulse** also strikes my ear as very odd, another misuse. That which is **abstained** from is a practice, or act, something we **do**, or the object of such an act. We don't do  impulses.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You can edit comments. This is my 3rd time receiving notification from same comment . **Edit:** Just a disclaimer, I’m asking this because a friend made this mistake and I’m trying to figure out his grammatical error and explain to him instead of saying “You’re wrong. Why? Because it’s like that.–“

Comment: @XPMai: You should **refrain** from chastising the people who are offering  answers to your question. It is bad form. I do edit comments. Sometimes I run into the arbitrary size limitation or hit the arbitrary 5 minute limit which prevents me from making the desired change, and am forced either to leave things as they are or to delete and recreate.

Comment: If you are asking _why_ we **refrain from** an action and **abstain from** a substance or habitual practice, I'm afraid you are going to have to tell your friend that the reason is _"because that is the way we use these verbs in English."_ N.b.: Your friend has **not** made a "grammatical error." She or he has used a verb in a way that is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the comments :

You **refrain from** doing something (a verb) in order to please someone else, whereas you **abstain from** an indulgent thing or activity (a noun or verb) because of a personal conviction that it is wrong or bad for you.

> He refrained from humming during the sermon.
>   She abstained from alcohol during her pregnancy.

Language is formed by customary use, so the only explanation for this usage is "because that is the custom in this country."